# In gam.plot (mgcv package in R) , I want to draw reference point and acceptable y axis

Tags: r, plot

I would like to make gam.plot with reference

for example, if I can refer to age:70, y axis would reveal "odds ratio"

not like below

With manual (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/mgcv.pdf),I performed various tries in s() or plot() or gam()

```
set.seed(1)
num <- 1000
age <- runif(num,min=65,max=85)
XX <- data.frame(age)
XX$death <- rbinom(num,1,(XX$age-72)^2/169)
head(XX)
plot(mgcv::gam(death ~ s(age),data=XX))
```

reference is age:70 and y axis reveal "odds ratio"

Comment: now, I cannot do it yet

Comment: I cannot do it yet